# why has the compile button disappeared from Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

The little triangle button on the top right side of visual studio code has just disappeared for some reason and now I can't even run my code. Does anyone know why?

I have no idea why it happened. But now the run code button just randomly disappeared.

Comment: what languages are you programming in? are you comparing to a previous state on the same machine? to another machine? what extensions do you have installed? did you uninstall any extension recently?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and open vscode when prompted.
It's the code runner extension which is the one that actually adds that button.
Check whether it is disabled or not, if it is, enable it again.

If that wasn't the case please open the extension settings and navigate to the bottom of the list, until you find `Code-runner: Show Run Icon In Editor Title Menu`, which you can tick to make it appear again.